# jquerymobile multiple pages on android with phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jquerymobile app that I started out in a single HTML file and am now trying to split across multiple files.

The initial file works fine and transitions to the next page fine; from there though it breaks down.  Links from any data-role page to another data-role page in the same file does not work.

In the example code below I'm trying to link the Add button in the ClientsPage footer to the data-role page with id of add_client.  Nothing happens when I deploy to Android.  If I run the same app in the browser it works fine.

```
  <div data-role="page" id="ClientsPage">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Clients</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a>First Client</a></li>
      <li><a>Second Client</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="#add_client" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add</a>
      <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Up</a>
      <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Down</a>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /page -->


  <!-- Start of add client -->
  <div data-role="page" id="add_client">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Clients</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content"> 


      <label for="ac_company">Company:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="ac_company" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_first_name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="ac_first_name" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_last_name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="ac_last_name" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="ac_email" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_address">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="address" id="ac_address" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_city">City:</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" id="ac_city" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_state">State:</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" id="ac_state" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_zip">Zip:</label>
      <input type="text" name="zip" id="ac_zip" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_country">Country:</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="ac_country" value=""/>

      <label for="ac_phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" id="ac_phone" value=""/>

      <a href="#MainPage" data-role="button">Login</a> 

      <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#RegisterPage">Register</a>.</p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add</a>
      <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Up</a>
      <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Down</a>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /page -->
```

[The rest of the code on GitHub](https://github.com/bigtunacan/StartingPhonegap/tree/tmp/hello-world/www)

Answer (score 0):

For me your code looks okay.

You can try to find out the process which makes it work in the below link. Seeing the source can help.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Comment: That link is an example of doing multiple pages in a single html file.  The problem I'm having is doing multiple pages across multiple html files.